# Changing DNS names on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, windows-server-2008-r2, windows

I just purchased a dedicated Windows Server 2008 R2 standard server and my provider gives me two DNS names as shown below.

- ns1.localhost.com
- ns2.localhost.com

Both of them are mapped to two different IP addresses.

I need to change them for example as ns1.example.com and ns2.example.com. I have my DNS manager on the server.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to register two [private] name servers with the ips of the server.

In your case you need to register name servers ns1.example.com and ns2.example.com with the ips of ns1.localhost.com and ns2.localhost.com. Both of the IPs are to be the ips inside the server.

For complete DNS resolution, you need to create DNS entries for the name servers under the local dns server.

Comment: hi. thanks. I did the same as on the following article but not sure if it works : http://programming4.us/desktop/2614.aspx

Comment: I configured one with DNS manager but I did configure it completely.